# BaseDevModeType: What is difference between the two enumerations?

Tags: c#, .net, printing, printer-properties, dev-mode

The BaseDevModeType defines two enumerations:

1. PrinterDefault.
2. UserDefault.

I understand that the devmode base structure is populated based on the enumerations.

But, How are these two devmodes different ?

What examples cases would each of the devmodes be different ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install a printer driver it comes with it's own device defaults.  The user can also "override" these defaults to set their own defaults.  For example the printer might default to no collation; but the user may want collation on by default for all their print jobs.  `UserDefault` should have the defaults the users has overridden from the device defaults.